# twitter Bootstrap 3.x form in modal do

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form contained inside a Twitter Bootstrap large modal dialog.

When I click the SUBMIT button, the form does NOT submit and the modal does NOT dismiss. The submitEventHandler() function is a fully tested and debugged function ensuring that all required fields have values entered/selected before allowing a submit event to occur.

[image]

```js
function initializeEventHandlers() {
    $('#ADD_BUTTON').on('click', function() {
      $('#id').val(null);
      $('#level').val(null);
      $('#name').val(null);
      $('#edit').val(false);

      $('#DEGREE_ENTRY').modal('show');
    });


    $('#DEGREE_FORM').submit(function() {
      $('#DEGREE_ENTRY').modal('hide');
      return submitEventHandler();
    });

  } // end function initializeEventHandlers()
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Page Title</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/open_sans.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/raleway.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/scriptina.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/glyphicons.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/glyphicons_filetypes.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/glyphicons_social.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/master.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://www.lcudev.com/_css/forms.css">

  <script language="javascript" src="http://www.lcudev.com/_javascript/modernizr.custom.92742.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="http://www.lcudev.com/_javascript/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="http://www.lcudev.com/_javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="http://www.lcudev.com/_javascript/master.js"></script>
  <script language="javascript" src="http://www.lcudev.com/_javascript/forms.js"></script>

  <script language="javascript">
    $('document').ready(function() {
      initializeEventHandlers();
    });
  </script>
  <noscript>
    <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=/miscellaneous/no_javascript.php">
  </noscript>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="CONTAINER" class="container">
    <header class="row">
      <h1>Life Christian University</h1>
      <a href="#">
        <img src="http://www.lcudev.com/_images/logos/lcu_logo_logotype_lg_20th_anniv.jpg" class="img-responsive">
      </a>
    </header>
    <div class="row">
      <!-- main menu code goes here -->
    </div>
    <ol class="breadcrumb">
      <!-- breadcrumbs <li> items goew here -->
    </ol>

    <div id="SYSTEM_MSG" class="alert alert-info bold col-md-12">Alert Message</div>

    <section class="row">
      <hgroup>
        <h1>Degrees Maintenance</h1>
      </hgroup>
      <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 2em;">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-8">
          <a id="ADD_BUTTON" type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm pull-right" href="#"><span class=\"glyphicons glyphicons-plus\"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Add a New Degree Code</a>
        </div>
      </div>

      <article class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3">
          <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed table-striped" summary="A list of classes for this campus.">
              <colgroup>
                <col id="ID">
                  <col id="LEVEL">
                    <col id="NAME">
                      <col id="ACTIONS">
              </colgroup>
              <thead>
                <tr>
                  <th scope="col" class="text-right">ID</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="text-center">Level</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="text-left">Name</th>
                  <th scope="col" class="text-left">Actions</th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                <tr>
                  <th class="text-center" colspan="4">There are 15 degreess defined</th>
                </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">A</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Associate in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="A" data-level="1" data-name="Associate in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="A" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">AA</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Associate of Arts in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="AA" data-level="1" data-name="Associate of Arts in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="AA" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">AD</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Advanced Diploma in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="AD" data-level="1" data-name="Advanced Diploma in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="AD" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">B</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Bachelor of</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="B" data-level="1" data-name="Bachelor of" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="B" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">BA</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Bachelor of Arts in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="BA" data-level="1" data-name="Bachelor of Arts in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="BA" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">BS</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Bachelor of Science in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="BS" data-level="1" data-name="Bachelor of Science in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="BS" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">CMP</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Bachelor of Church Planting & Missions</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="CMP" data-level="1" data-name="Bachelor of Church Planting & Missions" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="kill" data-id="CMP"
                    href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span></a> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">D</td>
                  <td class="text-center">1</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Diploma in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="D" data-level="1" data-name="Diploma in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="D" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">DLaw</td>
                  <td class="text-center">7</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Doctor of Laws in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="DLaw" data-level="7" data-name="Doctor of Laws in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="DLaw" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">DMin</td>
                  <td class="text-center">6</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Doctor of Ministry in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="DMin" data-level="6" data-name="Doctor of Ministry in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="kill" data-id="DMin" href="#"
                    title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span></a> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">DMis</td>
                  <td class="text-center">7</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Doctor of Missiology in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="DMis" data-level="7" data-name="Doctor of Missiology in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="kill" data-id="DMis" href="#"
                    title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span></a> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">Doc</td>
                  <td class="text-center">7</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Doctor of</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="Doc" data-level="7" data-name="Doctor of" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="Doc" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">EdD</td>
                  <td class="text-center">7</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Doctor of Education in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="EdD" data-level="7" data-name="Doctor of Education in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a class="kill" data-id="EdD" href="#"
                    title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span></a> 
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">M</td>
                  <td class="text-center">5</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Master of</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="M" data-level="5" data-name="Master of" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="M" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                  <td class="text-right">MA</td>
                  <td class="text-center">5</td>
                  <td class="text-left">Master of Arts in</td>
                  <td class="text-left"><a class="edit" data-id="MA" data-level="5" data-name="Master of Arts in" href="#" title="Click here to edit this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-pencil"></span></a>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <a class="kill" data-id="MA" href="#" title="Click here to delete this degree"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-delete"></span>
                    </a>
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </tbody>
            </table>
          </div>
        </div>
      </article>
      <div class="modal fade" id="DEGREE_ENTRY" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="classEntryModalDialog" aria-hidden="TRUE">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h4 class="modal-title">New Degree Entry</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form id="DEGREE_FORM" name="DEGREE_FORM" role="form" method="post" action="http://admin.lcudev.com/config/degrees/index.php">
                <input name="action" id="action" type="hidden" value="">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div id="id_group" class="form-group">
                      <label for="id" class="control-label">Degree ID*</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="id" id="id" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="10" required autofocus pattern="[a-zA-Z]+" title="Please enter a new degree ID code here" placeholder="degreeID" value="">
                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-sm">
       <span id="id_status" class="bold"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <span id="id_error" class="help-block">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-5">
                    <div id="level_group" class="form-group">
                      <label for="level" class="control-label">Degree Level*</label>
                      <select name="level" id="level" class="form-control" tabindex="20">
                        <option value="">- Select -</option>
                        <option value="1">Freshman</option>
                        <option value="2">Sophomore</option>
                        <option value="3">Junior</option>
                        <option value="4">Senior</option>
                        <option value="5">Masters</option>
                        <option value="6">DMin</option>
                        <option value="7">PhD</option>
                      </select>
                      <span id="level_error" class="help-block">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-offset-1">
                    <div id="name_group" class="form-group">
                      <label for="name" class="control-label">Degree Name*</label>
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <input name="name" id="name" type="text" class="form-control" tabindex="30" required pattern="[a-zA-Z ]+" title="Please enter the degree name here" placeholder="degree name" value="">
                        <span class="input-group-addon input-group-sm">
       <span id="name_status" class="bold"></span>
                        </span>
                      </div>
                      <span id="name_error" class="help-block">&nbsp;</span>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-md-2">&nbsp;</div>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
              <button name="CANCEL" id="CANCEL" type="button" class="btn btn-link" tabindex="50" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-ban"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Cancel &amp; Close</button>
              <button name="SUBMIT" id="SUBMIT" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" tabindex="40" form="DEGREE_FORM"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-upload"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Save This Degree</button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- /.modal-content -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal -->

      <!-- InstanceEndEditable -->


    </section>

    <div class="row">
      <button id="TOP" type="button" class="btn btn-xs btn-link" tabindex="32767"><span class="glyphicons glyphicons-up-arrow"></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;Back to Top of Page</button>
    </div>

    <footer class="row">
      &copy; Copyright 2015 by Life Christian University, Inc. &bull; All rights reserved. &bull; Unauthorized duplication of site content is strictly forbidden
      <p id="siteseal" style="margin-top: 6px"><span id="siteseal"><script type="text/javascript" src="https://seal.godaddy.com/getSeal?sealID=zfFa5wE7mSdFUIwGJyK7j2gy8j79He28Y1eOLBZL34xkPov1I8nxgEtNv"></script></span>
      </p>
    </footer>
  </div>
  <!-- end #CONTAINER -->

  <script language="javascript">
    <!-- TemplateBeginEditable name="BottomScript" -->
    $('#TOP').on('click', function() {
      scrollToTop();
    });
     <!-- TemplateEndEditable -->
  </script>
</body>
<!-- InstanceEnd -->

</html>
```

Is this a Bootstrap bug or am I missing something/using the wrong approach?

Comment: Do you get into submit handler at all? Post HTML code.

Comment: agree with @dfsq post your html. This is 100% sure not a Bootstrap bug

Comment: Post updated with full page code

Answer (score 1):

You should put the submit button inside the < form > block. The way you have used it submit button, there is no way for the browser, nor bootstrap to know the relation between these elements. Just move it inside.

```
<form>
....
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

will work.

Comment: In terms of layout, sometimes this is not easy to do, specially if you are using visual studio which forces some restrictions. but if you are not doing it, it is pretty easy to expand your form so it contains modal-content.

Comment: I thought that the following tag argument allowed placement of a SUBMIT button outside the <FORM> boundaries in HTML5: 

form="DEGREE_FORM"

Comment: Tried Arash's suggestion. No joy!